# How to create custom AR button

Tags: roomle

Does someone have any examples how to generate AR URL?
Reading Web SDK documentation, seems that there is no functionality to do that.

Found https://github.com/Roomle/roomle-button but not sure that`s still way to go since it has not been updated for 2 years.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to have your own button for AR? The roomle-button is deprecated and will no longer be maintained.

Comment: Yes we are trying to generate AR url and QR code. Generating hash in usm:frame:HASH was the problem. Just found that https://docs.roomle.com/web/api/classes/roomleconfigurator.html#getcurrentconfigurationhash might lead to solution.

Comment: OK. So we are able to generate correct usm:frame:HASH for current configuration but we are unable to activate link via https://www.roomle.com/t/cp/ar.html?id=usm:frame:hash&configuratorId=roomlePdc. Link becomes active only if AR button inside roomle admin is clicked. How to get this working on custom button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Roomle SDK you can use [saveCurrentConfiguration](https://docs.roomle.com/web/api/classes/roomleconfigurator.html#savecurrentconfiguration) to get the configuration id (hash) of the current configuration. Not sure what you used at the moment to obtain a configuration id but you need to call this in order to save it on the Roomle server and open it in another place.

Also make sure to set the `configuratorId` URL param when linking to the AR site.